# How to specify a range and perform a function accordingly in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, matrix, range

I need to perform the following function in matlab.

[image]

I had tried the following code but somehow my if statement is wrong. I'd like to know how to use the if statement efficiently here. If there is any other method in which i could perform the function please do help. My code is as follows

```
if (y(i,j) < -0.5, y(i,j) >= -1)
    f(i,j) = 0
elseif (y(i,j) < 0, y(i,j) >= -0.5)
    f(i,j) = 1
elseif (y(i,j) < 0.75, y(i,j) >= 0)
    f(i,j) = 2
elseif (y(i,j) < 1, y(i,j) >= 0.75)
    f(i,j) = 3
end
```

Here y(i,j) is a 1 x 256 matrix. Thanks

Comment: Your previous version with `elseif` is correct.  `else if` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the logical AND operator to tie two Boolean expressions together.  You are using a comma which is not correct:

```
if (y(i,j) < -0.5 && y(i,j) >= -1)
    f(i,j) = 0
elseif (y(i,j) < 0 && y(i,j) >= -0.5)
    f(i,j) = 1
elseif (y(i,j) < 0.75 && y(i,j) >= 0)
    f(i,j) = 2
elseif (y(i,j) < 1 && y(i,j) >= 0.75)
    f(i,j) = 3
end
```

However, it looks like you're using this in a `for` loop and I wouldn't perform the above in a loop.  Use logical indexing instead:

```
f(y < -0.5 & y >= 1) = 0;
f(y < 0 & y >= -0.5) = 1;
f(y < 0.75 & y >= 0) = 2;
f(y < 1 & y >= 0.75) = 3;
```

This is assuming that `f` is the same size as `y`.

Comment: Ouch, you are the fastest typer in the far west.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - Oh shoot lol. sorry my friend! Thanks for the +1 btw. :)

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, logical indexing is easier and I was able to do this for an even larger function too.

Comment: @Roshni191 - My pleasure :) I realize that I answered very quickly.  When you get the chance and if I have helped you, I wouldn't mind if you accepted my answer.  Thanks and good luck!